# Wrong font size on help in mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Viewing this page on my iPhone I have some lines that have the wrong font size and do not float correctly.

Looks like a problem with some class or tag which has not been reset for mobile devices correctly.

Comment: It's the rows with reputation: 2000, 250, 100, 15

Comment: Confirmed, it's the descriptions of the privilege that float down to the next line and are a different size